# Graphs of functions with fractional powers: $x^{p/q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, fractions

How does changing the value of $\dfrac{p}{q}$ affect the drawing of the graph (domain/range/shape, etc.)
How do you calculate asymptotes?

[image]

Below is a question dealing with this type of function. Can someone please refer to the explanations on how to go about solving these questions?
I have no idea because I don't understand these graphs

[image]

Comment: Do you know $\sqrt[m]{A^n}=A^{n/m}$?

Comment: yes :) i know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT :

The graph of $y=\sqrt[m]{(x-a)^n}$ is a graph such that the graph of $y=\sqrt[m]{x^n}$ is parallel-shifted by $a$ in the $x$ direction.

Since $y=f(x)$ has a maximal domain of $[-a, \infty)$...

Comment: well no because i dont understand how the n/m makes a difference to the domain. i mean multiple options have x-a.

Comment: see your chart. you'll find the difference of domains.

Comment: $x^{1/3}$ and $x^{2/3}$ has the domain $x\in\mathbb R.$ But your function does not have the domain $x\in\mathbb R.$ This means that your function is not in the form of $(x\pm a)^{1/3}, (x\pm a)^{2/3}.$

Comment: yup i got it - so its (x+a)^(3/2)right... thanks

Comment: Yes! that's right. You are welcome!